# Prevent Select Input value change conditionally

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I have this vue component:

```
<template>
    <div id="OrderTypeSelect" class="order-type-select">        
         <b-form-select v-model="curDocType" :options="options" class="mb-3">
        </b-form-select>        
    </div>
</template>
```

the value of the select input is bound to the Vuex store like this:

```
computed: {
        curDocType: {
            get () {
                return this.$store.state.curDocType
            },
            set (value) {
                 this.$store.commit('setcurDocType', value)                
            }
        }
    }
```

What I can't figure out is how to conditionally prevent the select value from changing. I've tried this:

```
computed: {
        curDocType: {
            get () {
                return this.$store.state.curDocType
            },
            set (value) {
                if (this.$store.state.curOrder == ""){
                    this.$store.commit('setcurDocType', value)
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Debe descartar");
                    this.curDocType.get() //This throws error!
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Even if I don't commit the value to the store, the value in the input field is changed.

I need to call `get()` again (or something else) to make this binding persistent when my condition is triggered:

```
if (this.$store.state.curOrder != "") {
  //Do not modify store and return the input selection to it's previous value
}
```

Comment: did you try  `reurn this.$store.state.curDocType` instead of `this.curDocType.get()`

Comment: `return this.$store.state.curDocType Doesn't work, the input value is changed even like this. Don't know if set() is supposed to return a value anyway. Not acording to the docs anyway: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case i recommend to use a data object item called `curDocType` and watch it instead of using computed property :

```
 <b-form-select v-model="curDocType" :options="options" class="mb-3">
```

data object  :

```
  data(){
     return{
         curDocType:this.$store.state.curDocType
        };
       }
```

watch property :

```
   watch:{
     curDocType(newval,oldval){
            if (this.$store.state.curOrder == ""){
                this.$store.commit('setcurDocType', newval)
            }else{
             this.$nextTick(() => {this.curDocType=this.$store.state.curDocType})
            }
         }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `<b-form-select v-model="curValue" @input="setValue" :options="options" class="mb-3">`
Where `curValue` is a variable in `data` and `setValue` is a method:

```
methods: {
    setValue(value) {
        if (this.$store.state.curOrder == "") {
            this.$store.commit('setcurDocType', value)
            this.curValue = value
        } else {
            console.log("Debe descartar");
            this.$nextTick(() => {this.curValue = this.$store.state.curDocType})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, also this has the same effect as my original code. The Input select value can be changed

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, try now please. Pay attention you've used `v-model` on component.

Comment: I'm afraid I still have the same result :( not working after these changes as well

Comment: I can see your example is working, maybe it's an issue with the libraries I'm using (bootstrap-vue) or Vuex store in the mix